# Delete files and folders older than x days in remote windows server using windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to windows powershell. I have a script to identify the files and folders older than x files and delete it. but I need a script to check the same in remote windows server and do the same. Here is my code:

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "3"
$TargetFolder = "D:\hudson_slave\workspace"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 

 foreach ($File in $Files)
     {
     if ($File -ne $NULL)
         {
         write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
           Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
         }
     else
         {
         Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
         }
     }
```

Could any one please help me to delete the 3 days older files and folders in remote server (using IP)

Comment: If you have access to the admin-share (d$) you could just try: $TargetFolder = "\\IP-adress or hostname\d$\hudson_slave\workspace"
ex. $TargetFolder = "\\192.168.0.20\d$\hudson_slave\workspace"

Comment: @Oggew: Thanks for the comment. Could you please let me know how to pass the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

As Oggew stated you can delete them through a share

```
$TargetFolder = "\\server\sharename\folder"
```

You can also create and enter a PSSession. This is like you would work in a powershell console on the remote host.

```
Enter-PSSession servername
```

This way you can run your code as is. To use this you must enable PSRemoting first.
Please take a look at [about_remote](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847900.aspx).

Additionally you can use this command to remove the files.

```
$Files | Remove-Item
```